# Compare 2 big string lists

Tags: c#

I have two lists of strings - this is not mandatory, i can convert them to any collection (list, dictionary, etc).

First is "text":

```
Birds sings
Dogs barks
Frogs jumps
```

Second is "words":

```
sing
dog
cat
```

I need to iterate through "text" and if line contains any of "words" - do one thing and if not another thing.

> Important: yes, in my case i need to find partial match ignoring case, like text "Dogs" is a match for word "dog". This is why i use .Contains and .ToLower().

My naive try looks like this:

```cs
            List<string> text = new List<string>();
            List<string> words = new List<string>();
            foreach (string line in text)
            {
                bool found = false;
                foreach (string word in words)
                {
                    if (line.ToLower().Contains(word.ToLower()))
                    {
                        ;// one thing
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!found)
                    ;// another
            }
```

Problem in size - 8000 in first list and ~50000 in second. This takes too many time.

How to make it faster?

Comment: Your example contains the word "sings" in the first list and "sing" in the second, your code tells me this would be a match, have you considered if that is a legal case? For instance, what if the first list contains the word "Abusing"? Is that a match with "sing"?

Comment: I ask because if it was a simple word search, and not part-of-word, you could stuff the second list in a hashset, and split the strings from the first list into words and simply look if each word was in the hashset, this should be fairly faster, but it would be much much harder to handle parts-of-word matches.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yes, this is intended.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you only want to match on the specific words in your `text` list: that is, if `text` contains "dogs", and `words` contains "dog", then that *shouldn't* be a match.

Note that this is **different** to what your code currently does.

Given this, we can construct a [`HashSet<string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.8) of all of the *words* in your `text` list. We can then query this very cheaply.

We'll also use [`StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase?view=netframework-4.8) to do our comparisons. This is a better way of doing a case-insensitive match than `ToLower()`, and ordinal comparisons are relatively cheap. If you're dealing with languages other than English, you'll need to consider whether you actually need [`StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.currentcultureignorecase?view=netframework-4.8) or [`StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.invariantcultureignorecase?view=netframework-4.8).

```
var textWords = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
foreach (var line in text)
{
    var lineWords = line.Split(' ');
    textWords.UnionWith(lineWords);
}

if (textWords.Overlaps(words))
{
    // One thing
}
else
{
    // Another
}
```

---

If this is **not** the case, and you do want to do a `.Contains` on each, then you can speed it up a bit by avoiding the calls to `.ToLower()`. Each call to `.ToLower()` creates a new string in memory, so you're creating two new, useless objects per comparison.

Instead, use:

```
if (line.IndexOf(word, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
```

As above, you might have to use `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` or `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` depending on the language of your strings. However, you should see a significant speedup if your strings are entirely ASCII and you use `OrdinalIgnoreCase` as this makes the string search a lot quicker.

If you're using .NET Framework, another thing to try is moving to .NET Core. .NET Core introduced a lot of optimizations in this area, and you might find that it's quicker.

---

Another thing you can do is see if you have duplicates in either `text` or `words`. If you have a lot, you might be able to save a lot of time. Consider using a `HashSet<string>` for this, or linq's `.Distinct()` (you'll need to see which is quicker).

Comment: His code shows otherwise though, since it uses a simple Contains. He says nothing about the code not doing what it wants, other than that it is too slow, so I assume he actually wants "contains".

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Indeed. I spend the first two paragraphs explaining this. Your comment on the OP is perfectly valid (and I'm the one that upvoted it): my post covers one of the two possible answers

Answer (score 0):

You can try using LINQ for the second looping construct.

```
            List<string> text = new List<string>();
            List<string> words = new List<string>();
            foreach (string line in text)
            {
                bool found = words.FirstOrDefault(w=>line.ToLower().Contains(w.ToLower()))!=null;
                if (found)
                 {
                     //Do something
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    //Another
                 }
             }
```

Might not be as fast as you want but it will be faster than before.

Comment: "*but it will be faster than before*" -- what makes you think this? I'd have thought it'd be a fair bit slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve the search algorithm.

```
    public static int Search(string word, List<string> stringList)
    {
        string wordCopy = word.ToLower();
        List<string> stringListCopy = new List<string>();
        stringList.ForEach(s => stringListCopy.Add(s.ToLower()));
        stringListCopy.Sort();

        int position = -1;

        int count = stringListCopy.Count;

        if (count > 0)
        {
            int min = 0;
            int max = count - 1;
            int middle = (max - min) / 2;

            int comparisonStatus = 0;

            do
            {
                comparisonStatus = string.Compare(wordCopy, stringListCopy[middle]);

                if (comparisonStatus == 0)
                {
                    position = middle;
                    break;
                }
                else if (comparisonStatus < 0)
                {
                    max = middle - 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    min = middle + 1;
                }

                middle = min + (max - min) / 2;
            } while (min < max);
        }

        return position;
    }
```

Inside this method we create copy of string list. All elements are lower case.
After that we sort copied list by ascending. This is crucial because the entire algorithm is based upon ascending sort.

If word exists in the list then the Search method will return its position inside list, otherwise it will return -1.

How the algorithm works?
Instead of checking every element in the list, we split the list in half in every iteration.
In every iteration we take the element in the middle and compare two strings (the element and our word). If out string is the same as the one in the middle then our search is finished. If our string is lexical before the string in the middle, then our string must be in the first half of the list, because the list is sorted by ascending. If our string is lexical after the string in the middle, then our string must be in the second half of the list, again because the list is sorted by ascending. Then we take the appropriate half and repeat the process.
In first iteration we take the entire list.

I've tested the Search method using these data:

```
        List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
        stringList.Add("Serbia");
        stringList.Add("Greece");
        stringList.Add("Egypt");
        stringList.Add("Peru");
        stringList.Add("Palau");
        stringList.Add("Slovakia");
        stringList.Add("Kyrgyzstan");
        stringList.Add("Mongolia");
        stringList.Add("Chad");

        Search("Serbia", stringList);
```

This way you will search the entire list of ~50,000 elements in 16 iterations at most.

Comment: you have shown how to implement a `binary search` the problem with this is. This is slower than the HashSet approach by "canton7". Also your binary search cant handle "Contains()" only an exact word match so "sing" and "sings" would fail.